# Why facebook album id is zero in FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am using FQL. I am using the following set of query to get info about album,

```
SELECT aid,src_small from photo where pid='100000244468314_1600187'
```

i get the following result,

```
{
  "data": [
  {
  "aid": "0",
  "src_small": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/545289_450190444999100_1364645489_t.jpg"
}
]
}
```

Then i gave the following query to get the album name and owner,

```
SELECT aid, owner, name, object_id FROM album WHERE aid="0"
```

But i get the following,

```
{
"data": [
]
}
```

Why is album id 0? and why it returns None? Please help. I am new to FQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT aid, owner, name, object_id FROM album 
  WHERE object_id IN 
    (SELECT album_object_id FROM photo where pid='100000244468314_1600187')
```

It looks like `aid` and `pid` fields are on their way to be deprecated in exchange for the `object_id` fields.

Comment: I tried the above query...it returned the same empty response

Comment: Do you get an `album_object_id` if you run just this part of the query? `SELECT album_object_id FROM photo where pid='100000244468314_1600187'` Is this photo yours? If not, have you requested the permissions you need in your access token?

Comment: oh yeah! got it... giving more permissions did the trick..and the above query is better. I will use this